# How do I successfully integrate a Middleman frontmatter variable in a javascript snippet in the layout page written in haml?

Tags: javascript, haml, preprocessor, middleman, yaml-front-matter

Yesterday I decided to go in for **Middleman** and **HAML** and they are awesome!
Since I don't want to create multiple layouts for just a value, I tried to use a **frontmatter variable** to change a value in a **javascript snippet** at the bottom of the layout page.

The javascript snippet is wrapped in the `:javascript` filter ([here's the reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter)), that triggers a jQuery plugin. The plugin needs some variables. The variable I want to change in other pages is `top`. According to the Middleman frontmatter guide page ([here's the reference](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/frontmatter/)), you just have to add `<% current_page.data.top %>` where you want that variable in the layout page. This string, written in **erb** is translated to **haml** in `= current_page.data.top` but when I run the page in a browser, the developer console tells `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='`.

*How do I successfully integrate a Middleman frontmatter variable in a javascript snippet in the layout page written in haml?*

The bottom of the layout page (where the snippet is) looks like this below:

```
/ content of the layout the page

:javascript
    $('#sidenav').simplerSidebar({
        opener: '#toggle-sidenav',
        top: = current_page.data.top
        animation: {
            easing: 'easeOutQuint'
        },
        sidebar: {
            align: 'right',
            width: 320,
            closingLinks: 'a',
            css: {
                zIndex: 3000
            }
        }
    });
```

the page I want to change looks like this:

```
---
top: 30
---

/ rest of the page
```

Comment: Shouldn't `top: = current_page.data.top` be `top: <%= current_page.data.top %>,`?

Comment: @JoshCrozier since the layout is written in HAML and not in ERB, the string is translated to `= current_page.data.top`http://haml.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to answer my question on my own. I read once again and more carefully the [Haml reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html) and in the [**Filter**](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#filters) section I read that **"Filters can have Ruby code interpolated with #{}."**.

Basically, while coding under a filter (no matter what filter it is), instead of using the strings provided by Middleman and Haml, you should use this one `#{current_page.data}`.

In my case the snippet code should be:

```
:javascript
    $('#sidenav').simplerSidebar({
        opener: '#toggle-sidenav',
        top: #{current_page.data.top},
        animation: {
            easing: 'easeOutQuint'
        },
        sidebar: {
            align: 'right',
            width: 320,
            closingLinks: 'a',
            css: {
                zIndex: 3000
            }
        }
    });
```